# Como encontrar el dato menor, en miles de datos?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Les comento, tengo que encontrar el numero menor en un arreglo que tiene miles de datos, si bien lo hice comparando uno por uno, pero siente que es muy tardado, como harian ustedes en este caso para este tipo de algoritmo.
Les dejo el algoritmo que realice.

```
menor = dato[0];
for(let i=0;i<dato.length;i++){
    if(dato[i] < menor){
        menor = dato[i];
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript proporciona la función *built-in* `Math.min()` que admite un número variable de argumentos y te devuelve el mínimo de todos ellos. Por desgracia no admite una lista como parámetro, pero por suerte en las versiones modernas de JavaScript tenemos el operador de *spreading* (que son tres puntos `...`  delante de una variable), que permite convertir una lista en una serie de parámetros.

Usando este operador la solución sería tan simple como:

```
let menor = Math.min(...datos)
```

Antes de que este operador existiera era frecuente utilizar `funcion.apply()` para lograr un resultado similar, esto es, aplicar la `funcion` en cuestión sobre una lista, de modo que la función reciba en vez de la lista, los valores que hay en ella como si fueran parámetros separados. La sintaxis de `apply()` sin embargo es un poco fea, ya que hay que pasarle dos parámetros, a pesar de que el primero no use usa, siendo el segundo la lista en cuestión. Quedaría entonces así:

```
let menor = Math.min.aply(null, datos)
```

Cualquiera de estas dos versiones sería en principio la solución más eficiente, ya que para empezar la lista se recorre una sola vez para encontrar el menor (complejidad O(n)), y además ese recorrido no lo haces tú escribiendo un bucle en JS, sino que lo hace el propio intérprete JS que está escrito en un lenguaje más rápido y optimizado y lo hará mucho antes.

### Bonus

No obstante, vamos a comprobar si la teoría es correcta y vamos a cronometrar cuánto tarda cada uno de los métodos propuestos en encontrar el valor menor en un array de 40000 números, que genero así:

```
datos=Array.from({length: 40000}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 40));
```

- Tu bucle (el que planteas en la pregunta) tarda 1.855ms
- La solución propuesta por aeportugal (usando `reduce()`) tarda 1.8049, un poco menos que el bucle.
- Ordenar la lista y tomar después el primer elemento (esto es: `datos.sort()[0]`) tarda 9.265ms. Como ves tarda más incluso que tu bucle, y eso que el método `sort()` es también un *built-in* implementado en un lenguaje eficiente, pero es que ordenar una lista tiene complejidad mayor de O(n), incluso con los algoritmos más eficientes, por lo que esta solución será más lenta que tu bucle a partir de un cierto tamaño de la lista.
- Aplicar la función `min` sobre la lista (el segundo método en mi respuesta) tarda 0.25ms
- Usar el *spreading* (`min(...datos)`) tarda 0.125ms

Answer (score 2):

En programación no hay que reiniventar la rueda cuando de funciones y métodos built-in se trata. Cualquier cosa que intentes será más lento que un método integrado, ya que los mismos están optimizados y hechos en otros lenguajes de nivel más bajo para maximizar eficiencia.

Una forma bastante óptima de buscar el menor valor, ES6, sería:

```
let menor = dato.reduce((a,b)=>Math.min(a,b), Infinity);
```

Comment: De acuerdo con lo de usar funciones built-in, pero en este caso debido a que usas `reduce` estás iterando de todas formas por todos los elementos de la lista y para cada uno aplicando una invocación de la función `min` con dos elementos. Dudo que esto sea mucho más rápido que la comparación `a<b`. Lo que en cambio sería mucho más rápido sería usar `min()` sobre todos los elementos de la lista, con la sintaxis: `menor = Math.min(...datos)`